# Document Timestamp field throwing error when unwrapping as Timestamp

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, document

I'm trying to retrieve a document with a Timestamp value from firestore. When I unwrap it like this:

```swift
let dateCreated = document.get("created") as! Timestamp
```

it throws the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSTaggedDate' (0x1b3cf66a0) to 'FIRTimestamp' (0x104bec868).

I've tried using `document.data["created"] as! Timestamp` but it throws the same error.

Is there a different way to retrieve Timestamps from firestore? Or is there something that I'm missing in my code? I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Firestore has a setting now called `areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled` and you need to set it to true in the appDelegate.

Comment: That setting has been removed from recent SDKs as far as I know, so consider upgrading to the latest release.